# How to resolve a #Name? error in Excel when using IF Logic with TODAY function

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am working with a table of data that includes hire dates of employees. I want the adjacent column to first check whether the [HIRE DATE] is blank. If blank; I want it to return NO. If not blank, I want it to check whether that hire date is within 6 months from today (6 past months) and return YES if true and NO if false.

I have tried the following formula but I keep receiving a "#NAME?" error message and I can't figure out how to resolve this. I feel like this formula is close but something is definitely off.

=IF([HIRE DATE]="",NO,(IF([HIRE DATE]>TODAY()-180,YES,NO)))

Comment: what is `[HIRE DATE]`

Comment: `NO` and `YES` should be in quotes.  `"NO"` and `"YES"`

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
// change this
=IF([HIRE DATE]="",NO,(IF([HIRE DATE]>TODAY()-180,YES,NO)))
// to this
=IF([HIRE DATE]="","NO",(IF([HIRE DATE]>TODAY()-180,"YES","NO")))
```